# amcharts configure the generated chart with a title and background color to be exported as PDF

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

Using Amcharts, I am able to generate the chart for my dynamic response-data. but while exporting it as PDF, it's downloading with white background only( i want it in green background though). I have set the background for the chart div using CSS, which works well in the UI. But while downloading it, the background gets white.

Also I would need to add the title to chart exported as PDF (Like: 'Monthly ABC Status' from 01/08/2018 To 31/08/2018).

Here is my code :  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w0rd2cs3/5/)

```
   var chartData = [ {
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 4025,
  "color": "#FF0F00"
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882,
  "color": "#FF6600"
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809,
  "color": "#FF9E01"
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322,
  "color": "#FCD202"
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122,
  "color": "#F8FF01"
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114,
  "color": "#B0DE09"
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984,
  "color": "#04D215"
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711,
  "color": "#0D8ECF"
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665,
  "color": "#0D52D1"
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580,
  "color": "#2A0CD0"
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443,
  "color": "#8A0CCF"
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441,
  "color": "#CD0D74"
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395,
  "color": "#754DEB"
}, {
  "country": "Italy",
  "visits": 386,
  "color": "#DDDDDD"
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "visits": 384,
  "color": "#999999"
}, {
  "country": "Taiwan",
  "visits": 338,
  "color": "#333333"
}, {
  "country": "Poland",
  "visits": 328,
  "color": "#000000"
} ];


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "backgroundColor":"green",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "country",
  "depth3D": 20,
  "angle": 30,

  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 90,
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },

  "valueAxes": [ {
    "title": "Visitors"
  } ],

  "graphs": [ {
    "valueField": "visits",
    "colorField": "color",
    "type": "column",
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "fillAlphas": 1
  } ],

  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false,
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false
  },

  "export": {
    "enabled": true
  }
} );
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the [`backgroundColor`](https://github.com/amcharts/export/#user-content-complete-list-of-available-export-settings) in the export config to make it work:

```
export: {
  // ...
  backgroundColor: "#008855", //replace with your color
  // ...
}
```

As for the title, one way you can set it is by creating a `pdfMake` property containing your new content:

```
"pdfMake": {
    "content": [ "'Monthly ABC Status' from 01/08/2018 To 31/08/2018" , {
        "image": "reference", //exported image
        "fit": [ 523.28, 769.89 ] // fit image to A4
    } ]
}
```

Demo below:

```js
var chartData = [{
  "country": "USA",
  "visits": 4025,
  "color": "#FF0F00"
}, {
  "country": "China",
  "visits": 1882,
  "color": "#FF6600"
}, {
  "country": "Japan",
  "visits": 1809,
  "color": "#FF9E01"
}, {
  "country": "Germany",
  "visits": 1322,
  "color": "#FCD202"
}, {
  "country": "UK",
  "visits": 1122,
  "color": "#F8FF01"
}, {
  "country": "France",
  "visits": 1114,
  "color": "#B0DE09"
}, {
  "country": "India",
  "visits": 984,
  "color": "#04D215"
}, {
  "country": "Spain",
  "visits": 711,
  "color": "#0D8ECF"
}, {
  "country": "Netherlands",
  "visits": 665,
  "color": "#0D52D1"
}, {
  "country": "Russia",
  "visits": 580,
  "color": "#2A0CD0"
}, {
  "country": "South Korea",
  "visits": 443,
  "color": "#8A0CCF"
}, {
  "country": "Canada",
  "visits": 441,
  "color": "#CD0D74"
}, {
  "country": "Brazil",
  "visits": 395,
  "color": "#754DEB"
}, {
  "country": "Italy",
  "visits": 386,
  "color": "#DDDDDD"
}, {
  "country": "Australia",
  "visits": 384,
  "color": "#999999"
}, {
  "country": "Taiwan",
  "visits": 338,
  "color": "#333333"
}, {
  "country": "Poland",
  "visits": 328,
  "color": "#000000"
}];


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
  "theme": "light",
  "type": "serial",
  "backgroundColor": "green",
  "dataProvider": chartData,
  "categoryField": "country",
  "depth3D": 20,
  "angle": 30,

  "categoryAxis": {
    "labelRotation": 90,
    "gridPosition": "start"
  },

  "valueAxes": [{
    "title": "Visitors"
  }],

  "graphs": [{
    "valueField": "visits",
    "colorField": "color",
    "type": "column",
    "lineAlpha": 0.1,
    "fillAlphas": 1
  }],

  "chartCursor": {
    "cursorAlpha": 0,
    "zoomable": false,
    "categoryBalloonEnabled": false
  },

  "export": {
    "enabled": true,
    "backgroundColor": "#008855",
    "pdfMake": {
      "content": ["'Monthly ABC Status' from 01/08/2018 To 31/08/2018", {
        "image": "reference", //exported image
        "fit": [523.28, 769.89] // fit image to A4
      }]
    }
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #008855;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/serial.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/plugins/export/export.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/3/themes/light.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

The github readme has most of the information pertaining to the plugin and this [advanced tutorial](http://www.amcharts.com/kbase/export-charts-advanced/) has more information on how to customze the layout to include more than just one chart. The plugin uses pdfMake for its PDF export functionality, so the [pdfMake documentation](http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted) is another useful resource for layout information.

Comment: thanks, it really helps. Now I can see the title, but Can I format it with the center alignment ? also if the legands (tabular format data) can be added along with the chart, Please advise!

Comment: If you look at the pdfMake docs I linked, you can find out how to align the text. `{ text: 'Your title', alignment: 'center' }` instead of just a string. You can enable legends by adding a `legend` object to your makeChart call. See the [legend API documentation](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmLegend) on how to further customize it. If you need a legend marker for every column, look at [this example](https://www.amcharts.com/kbase/generate-legend-markers-column/)